# xcode - unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c

I called method in another class (they are both singletons).

WebserviceHelper.h

```
@interface WebserviceHelper : NSObject {
    int currentType;
    NSString *SERVER_URL;
    WebserviceManager *webService;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id delegate;

- (void)retrieveStudentwithCode:(NSString *)code {
    currentType = STUDENT_TYPE;
    NSString *param = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"token=uencom&cid=%@", code];
    NSString *link = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@getStudentInfo", SERVER_URL];
    [webService retrieveData:link withParameters:param];
}
```

After call webservice and get data it cached here in received data. I check and it works fine
but when it deliver to `didFinishLoading` error happen here

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)receivedData {
    data = [NSMutableData new];
    [data appendData:receivedData];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    [self stopPostingToWebservice];
    //it carsh here
    [delegate: data];
}
```

Call stack:

```
2014-08-20 10:39:05.187 School-Link[1030:60b] -[WebserviceHelper :]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa88a420
2014-08-20 10:39:05.188 School-Link[1030:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[WebserviceHelper :]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa88a420'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x01bf31e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x018f08e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x01c90243 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x01be350b ___forwarding___ + 1019
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x01be30ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   School-Link                         0x00030c82 -[WebserviceManager connectionDidFinishLoading:] + 242
    6   Foundation                          0x016b9e49 ___NSURLConnectionDidFinishLoading_block_invoke + 40
    7   Foundation                          0x016507e1 __65-[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:]_block_invoke + 62
    8   Foundation                          0x014d8f5e -[NSURLConnectionInternalConnection invokeForDelegate:] + 119
    9   Foundation                          0x014d8ec6 -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:] + 208
    10  Foundation                          0x014d8dd8 -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withActiveConnectionAndDelegate:] + 76
    11  Foundation                          0x014d9188 _NSURLConnectionDidFinishLoading + 43
    12  CFNetwork                           0x02a3169f ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic26_delegate_didFinishLoadingEU13block_pointerFvvE_block_invoke + 111
    13  CFNetwork                           0x02a2f3de ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic18_withDelegateAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvP16_CFURLConnectionPK33CFURLConnectionClientCurrent_VMaxE_block_invoke_2 + 104
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x01b94c69 CFArrayApplyFunction + 57
    15  CFNetwork                           0x02998441 _ZN19RunloopBlockContext7performEv + 155
    16  CFNetwork                           0x02a7a3f4 _ZThn16_N19RunloopBlockContext24multiplexerClientPerformEv + 20
    17  CFNetwork                           0x02998257 _ZN17MultiplexerSource7performEv + 299
    18  CFNetwork                           0x0299806c _ZN17MultiplexerSource8_performEPv + 76
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x01b7c77f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x01b7c1d5 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 437
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x01b991ae __CFRunLoopRun + 910
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x01b989d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x01b987eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    24  GraphicsServices                    0x0338d5ee GSEventRunModal + 192
    25  GraphicsServices                    0x0338d42b GSEventRun + 104
    26  UIKit                               0x005b0f9b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    27  School-Link                         0x00018f6d main + 141
    28  libdyld.dylib                       0x03026701 start + 1
    29  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: The way your passing the object to your delegate is wrong! Follow the @trojanfoe syntax

Comment: i am new to objective c , so i dont have any experience in that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, have a protocol declaration in WebserviceHelper.h like

```
@protocol studentDataDelegate <NSObject>

    -(void)WebserviceHelper:(WebserviceHelper *)webserviceHelper didStudentDataDownloadCompleteWithData:(NSMutableData *)data;

@end
```

WebserviceHelper.m

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    [self stopPostingToWebservice];

    [self.delegate WebserviceHelper:self didStudentDataDownloadCompleteWithData:data];
}
```

so which ever class confirms to the above protocol should implement the delegate method like,

```
@interface RequestingDataClass : UIViewController <studentDataDelegate>
```

by doing this you will receive the warning that you have not implemented `didStudentDataDownloadCompleteWithData:`method so do it like

```
      -(void)WebserviceHelper:(WebserviceHelper *)webserviceHelper didStudentDataDownloadCompleteWithData:(NSMutableData *)data;
    {
webserviceHelper.delegate=self; 
    // Do something with the `data`
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You do no show the declaration of the delegate, however this statement:

```
[delegate: data];
```

Should be:

```
[delegate haveSomeData:data];
```

(or something similar)

Comment: should i create new method in anther class to handle the data from this one

Comment: @MohammadShaker Well if you want to inform the delegate that data has been received, which is what I assume you'd like to do, you will need a method similar to that shown in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

did you create protocol in your WebserviceHelper.h file like this?

```
@protocol WebserviceHelperDelegate <NSObject>

@required
-(void)reciveData:(NSData *)data;//or your method

@end
```

decleare a property

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) id <WebserviceHelperDelegate> delegate;
```

then call this method like

```
 - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
   [self stopPostingToWebservice];
   //it carsh here
   [self.delegate reciveData: data];
 }
```

And implement this method from where you call webservice class and assign delegate

```
-(void)reciveData:(NSData *)data{
}
```

Comment: i try this code , it make many problem with me , i work in my friend code , i dont know  how he build it , but thank you friend